# How to Inspect an Int64 of a Manage application using Windbg

Tags: c#, windows, debugging, windbg

When using windbg to debug a managed process how can I see the value of a Int64? For example I have the following constructor which has as its first parameter a Int64.

```
ItemQuote quote = new ItemQuote(1234567890987654L, "5mm Super Widgets", 1000, 12999, true, false);
```

Using the windbg debugger I set a break point at the afore mentioned constructor to inspect its arguments. The disassembly yields the following.

```
Child SP       IP Call Site
0042f05c 0043025a EncodingInformation.ItemQuote..ctor(Int64, System.String, Int32, Int32, Boolean, Boolean)
    PARAMETERS:
        this (0x0042f060) = 0x01fe3908
        itemNumber (0x0042f07c) = 0x3c97ea86
        itemDescription (0x0042f05c) = 0x01fe2378
        quantity (0x0042f078) = 0x000003e8
        unitPrice (0x0042f074) = 0x000032c7
        discounted (0x0042f070) = 0x00000001
        inStock (0x0042f06c) = 0x00000000
```

using the .formats command on the itemNumber parameter does not yield what I would expect to see.

```
0:000> .formats 0x3c97ea86
Evaluate expression:
  Hex:     3c97ea86
  Decimal: 1016588934
  Octal:   07445765206
  Binary:  00111100 10010111 11101010 10000110
  Chars:   <...
  Time:    Tue Mar 19 21:48:54 2002
  Float:   low 0.0185444 high 0
  Double:  5.02262e-315
```

What should I do to see the actual passed in value of = 1234567890987654L ?

Comment: Are you sure this is the call you are tracking, not another call with different parameters?

Comment: to view an int64 you use  dq <address>  or  ? qwo <address>

Comment: @dcrearer, what about using kb command to print out native callstack. You can find there your args. Also, is it Release or Debug mode?

Comment: You are only getting 32 bits of the 64-bit value.  1234567890987654 == 0x00462D5'3C97EA86.  You have to dump memory at the given address (0x0042f07c) to see all 64 of them.  Using Windbg to debug a managed program is self-inflicted punishment that is best avoided.

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan: `kb` will not work well for a managed app (tagged C# and see the title)

Comment: @Thomas Weller , yes, you're right. But the problem is when I tried  it with assembly built in Release mode, !clrstack -a didn't show anything (it shows <no data> on args)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand, you're debugging x86 app and because of it you see  lower part of long in !clrstack -a command. 
As @blabb mentioned , you can use dq to get the value of address:
[image]

Comment: You can use `dq ... L1` if you know there's only one value to be inspected